# Python Functions Default Values

Tags: python, function, default-value

Hi all I am felling pretty stuck on this problem and cant figure out where to start. Any help would be appreciated!

The problem is below.

Write a function score_input() that takes parameters test_name, test_score, and invalid_message that validates the test_score, then returns a string.

Write the function with the following requirements
The test_name is a mandatory parameter and will not need validation.
The test_score is optional, with default value that is negative, e.g. -1, and will be validated to be between 0-100
The invalid_message is optional, with default value 'Invalid test score!'
In the function add appropriate code to validate the parameter value for test_score.
Return the string with test name and score if it passes validation; otherwise return the test name with invalid_message.

Comment: Please provide some details of what you have attempted to do. We can tell you how to do this, but you will not learn if we do.

Answer (score 0):

The question wasn’t too clear but is this what you’re looking for?

```
def score_input(test_name, test_score:int=0, invalid_message=‘Invalid Test Score!’) -> str:
    if 0 <= test_score <= 100:
        return f’{test_name}, {test_score}’
    else:
        return f’{test_name}, {invalid_message}’
```